# Azure SignalR serverless mode, Negotiate fails through Azure function app

Tags: azure-functions, signalr

I have been trying to figure out if there is way to use the Azure SignalR serverless mode to negotiate through an Azure function app that does not allow unauthenticated Requests. The key issue here is the **not allowing unauthenticated requests** part. Turning this off makes this function work fine, but I currently have this setup to be authenticated through my Identity Provider (security reasons). And of course, this works when running locally, as the this doesn't require authenticated requests. I assume this is an issue of the communication coming back from the Azure SignalR service, not have the proper authentication to talk back to the function app(to setup the connection). This is also not an authorization issue of access to this function app, as I have 40 other functions that work just fine to access through my application.

[Function App Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nwOq.jpg)

Using something of an example like this code linked

[Serveless Development](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config.md)

I have searched other questions around this in StackOverFlow and others in comments have asked this with no response answers around similar issues in previous years. Does anyone know of a way to get this to work this way?

I have tried adding azure Identity Access roles to the services both ways to see if that would work allowing specific access. And that works to allow my function app to request access to the SignalR instance. But this wasn't an issue of the initial access, as the access to the SignalR instance works fine with an Access Key as well.

I tried to find logging in the Kudu console around this, and the only things I could find were for the were for function calls that actually made it through. As this is the 401 unauthorized stopped by the authentication settings on the function app, I can't find the logs for this, or they are inaccessible through the kudu console.(searched through ISS program files, as well as others).

Used lots of methods, but this is one example of the generalized methods that utilizes the Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.extensions.SignalRService.

As asked for the code in general comments:

```
public class SignalRTestHub : ServerlessHub
{
  [FunctionName("negotiate")]
   public SignalRConnectionInfo 
   Negotiate([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]HttpRequest 
    req)
{
    return Negotiate(req.Headers["x-ms-signalr-user-id"], 
    GetClaims(req.Headers["Authorization"]));
}

[FunctionName(nameof(OnConnected))]
public async Task OnConnected([SignalRTrigger]InvocationContext 
invocationContext, ILogger logger)
{
    await Clients.All.SendAsync(NewConnectionTarget, new 
NewConnection(invocationContext.ConnectionId));
    logger.LogInformation($"{invocationContext.ConnectionId} has 
connected");
}

[FunctionName(nameof(Broadcast))]
public async Task Broadcast([SignalRTrigger]InvocationContext 
invocationContext, string message, ILogger logger)
{
    await Clients.All.SendAsync(NewMessageTarget, new 
NewMessage(invocationContext, message));
    logger.LogInformation($"{invocationContext.ConnectionId} 
broadcast {message}");
}

[FunctionName(nameof(OnDisconnected))]
public void OnDisconnected([SignalRTrigger]InvocationContext 
invocationContext)
{
}
```

}

Another example:

```
 [FunctionName("negotiate")]
 public static SignalRConnectionInfo Negotiate(
 [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, Route = "negotiate")] 
 HttpRequest req,
 [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = AzureConstants.SignalRHub , 
 UserId = "{headers.x-ms-client-principal-name}")] 
 SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo,
 ILogger log
 )
 {
    return connectionInfo;
 }
```

Both of these work fine with the Azure function when you allow unauthenticated requests, but not when you set it to not.

**!!!!Solved:** For any future readers with issues as such:
I had some wrong assumptions, the angular/signalr package doesn't work like the HTTP Client out the box and strips the auth token. You need to authenticate against your api. Using just data from MSAL that comes across you can do this by passing in the bearer token with headers and set the Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Auth-Token".

For me.. not sure if this will work for other but I will put some generalized code here to explain this. I use the angular MSAL library to authenticate with access to an api scope. I then check the tokens from cache for the one I am looking for with the bearer token, I received from login to this specific api. **Disclaimer** no guarantee this is a good way to do this. Just a way to get it working from just pulling data you receive from Msal, assuming you setup your azure environment in certain ways.

```
export type MsalTokenClass =
{
cachedAt: number;
clientId: string;
credentialType: string;
environment: string;
expiresOn: number;
extendedExpiresOn: number;
homeAccountId: string;
realm: string;
secret : string;
target: string;
tokenType: string;
}

isMyType(o: any): o is MsalTokenClass {
    return "cachedAt" in o && "clientId" in o && "credentialType" 
in o && "environment" in o && "expiresOn" in o && 
"extendedExpiresOn" in o && "homeAccountId" in o && "realm" in o && 
"secret" in o && "target" in o && "tokenType" in o;
}

getAndSetApiToken()
{
    let cache :any  = this.authService.instance.getTokenCache();
    let getStorage = cache.storage.browserStorage.windowStorage;

    for(const key in getStorage)
    {
      let current = getStorage[key];
      let parsed : any; 

      try 
      {
          parsed = JSON.parse(current);

          if(this.isMyType(parsed))
          {
              console.log("Current parsed = ", parsed);
              console.log("Current parsed target = ", 
              parsed.target);
                //this is like 
               this should mirror what you setup in the 
              msalinterceptorConfigFactory protectedResourceMap 
              scope 
              i.e. 
              https://youtenant.com/myapi/api.ReadWrite
              if(parsed.target ===  
               environment.resourceIds.apiScope + api.ReadWrite
              )
              {
                  console.log("Current Bearer = ", parsed.secret);
                  this.currentBearerToken = parsed.secret;
              }
          }
          else
          {
              console.log("not the right type");
          }
      }
      catch{
          console.log("Not Json type");
          continue;
      }
   
    }
}

 public startConnection = () => 
{
    this.getAndSetApiToken();
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(this.apiAddress,
    {        
        headers: 
        { 
            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ this.currentBearerToken,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'X-Auth-Token'
        },
    })
    .configureLogging(LogLevel.Trace)
    .build();

    this.hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => 
        {   
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: 
        ' + err))
}
```

Comment: is it solved?! solved in js.

Comment: It was solved in js(ts) yes. Thanks for checking up.. not sure how to close out?

Comment: Just post your answer in ``` Your Answer```